# How to only show a section of a JComponent/SwingNode/Java FX Pane

Tags: java, javafx, components, jcomponent, pane

I'm building a Java FX music application and I have a Java FX Pane which contains a SwingNode which contains a JComponent and I want to be able to hide the top and bottom of this component and only show the middle section.

If I resize the Pane to be smaller than the Component then it displays just the top section of the Component, like this [Top section of Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozonM.png), but I would like a way to move the component upwards so that the middle section is visible and the top and bottom are cropped [Middle section of Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYd9X.png)

Anyone know a way to do this? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clip the outer area simply, wrap the node to a `Pane`, set negative `LayoutXY` and suitable `MaxSize`. When the outer area overlaps the other `Node`s, clipping may be required. For example:

```
Pane viewPort = new Pane();
viewPort.getChildren().add(yourSwingNode);

// Top 200px and bottom 200px of yourSwingNode will be trimed.
yourSwingNode.setLayoutY(-200.0);
yourSwingNode.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((o, ov, nv) -> {
    viewPort.setMaxHeight(nv.getHeight() - 400.0);
});

// Set a clip for the layout bounds of Pane if you need
Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
viewPort.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((o, ov, nv) -> {
    clip.setWidth(nv.getWidth());
    clip.setHeight(nv.getHeight());
});
viewPort.setClip(clip);
```